# Merging two different queries

Tags: mysql

Hello guys I have two diferrent queries :

```
SELECT ROUND(x, -1)    AS range,
COUNT(*)    
FROM  tbl_name
GROUP  BY range;
```

and

```
SELECT ROUND(y, -1)    AS range,
    COUNT(*)    
    FROM   tbl_name
    GROUP  BY range;
```

both queries return two columns like this:
0| 22

I want to combine both of these queries which in returns 3 coloumns like this 
0| 22 | 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one row, then the solution is trivial.  Just use a `join`.  Something like:

```
select q1.range, q1.cnt, q2.cnt
from (<query1>) q1 join (<query2>) q2 on q1.range = q2.range;
```

The problem occurs when the two queries produce different values for `range`.  Then a simple `join` will not work.  SQL offers the `full outer join`, but MySQL does not support it.  In this case, you can do:

```
select range, sum(xcnt), sum(ycnt)
from ((SELECT ROUND(x, -1) AS range, COUNT(*) as xcnt, 0 as ycnt
       FROM  tbl_name
       GROUP BY range
      ) union all
      (SELECT ROUND(y, -1) AS range, 0, COUNT(*)    
       FROM   tbl_name
       GROUP  BY range
      )
     ) t
group by range;
```